# How do I shorten a clearcase view's load directory?

Tags: clearcase

In Clearcase I have a VOB with a path like this:

```
\Department\ProductGroup\Product1\Development
```

I have a view with a Config Spec like this:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../mybranch/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch mybranch
load \Department\ProductGroup\Product1
```

All the source code for Product1 is in the Development directory.  Nothing I care about exists outside this directory.  All references in the code are relative to this directory.

I have created the above Clearcase view in the directory c:\dev

Presently the above setup creates a directory:

```
c:\dev\Department\ProductGroup\Product1\Development
```

All the parent directories to `Development` are empty.  I'd rather have just the following directories.

```
c:\dev\Product1
```

Where `c:\dev\Product1` mapped to the VOB path `\Department\ProductGroup\Product1\Development`.  Is this possible?

Comment: As specified in my answer, if 'subst' does not work for you (because it is limited), moving your directory (ct move) is a good workaround and will result is a MUCH shorter path length. It may however disrupt some classpath or other environment scripts.

Answer (score 1):

1/ Why not only load \Department\ProductGroup\Product1\Development ?

```
load /Department/ProductGroup/Product1/Development
```

Note: you can use '`/`', easier than '`\`' and Windows config spec does interpret it correctly.

1bis/ If you want to keep a general rule, you could use some "**cleaning rules**"

Consider this config spec
(**test it in a dynamic view first**, to check quickly -- that is without endless update reloading steps -- if the result does match what you need: files under `Development` and no files anywhere else)

```
element * CHECKEDOUT

# read/write selection rule for the directory and sub-directory
# where you need to work
element /Department/ProductGroup/Development/... .../mybranch/LATEST
element /Department/ProductGroup/Development/... /main/LATEST -mkbranch mybranch

# specific selection rule for the parent directories of Development
# those rules do not contain a mkbranch directive
element /Department/ProductGroup  .../mybranch/LATEST
element /Department/ProductGroup /main/LATEST
element /Department  .../mybranch/LATEST
element /Department /main/LATEST

# cleaning rule right there: anything outside /Department/ProductGroup/Development
# will not be selected, hence not loaded
element /Department/* -none

load \Department
```

That way, you always keep the same load rule `load \Department`, and your selection rules do the cleaning for you.

2/ Regarding your path issue, you can use Symlink but the easiest way is to use a **subst**

```
subst X: c:\dev\Department\ProductGroup\Product1\Development
```

And you could go on using your snapshot view within X:\

BUT that would not work because ClearCase needs:

- view.dat (the hidden file indicating a directory tree is in fact a snapshot view)
- a vob (which is `Department` in your case. `ProductGroup\Product1\Development` is a path within the Vob `Department`)

  X:>ct lsview -l -full -pro -cview
  cleartool: Error: Cannot get view info for current view: not a ClearCase object.
  X:>ct ls
  cleartool: Error: Pathname is not within a VOB: "."

For those same reasons, **a hardlink with [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) on windows will not work**:

```
c:\dev>junction Product1 Department\ProductGroup\Product1
Junction v1.05 - Windows junction creator and reparse point viewer
Copyright (C) 2000-2007 Mark Russinovich
Systems Internals - http://www.sysinternals.com

Created: C:\dev\Product1
Targetted at: C:\dev\Department\ProductGroup\Product1

C:\cc\xxx>ct ls
cleartool: Error: Pathname is not within a VOB: "."
```

So what you can do is:

```
subst X: c:\dev
```

That combined with the specific load rules from 1/ or the cleaning rules from 1bis/ will give you:

- a slightly shorter path
- no extra empty sub-directories

---

2bis/ "Devious" solution:

From the ClearCase explorer, move `Development` from `Department\ProductGroup\Product1` to `Department`! That move will be recording within '`mybranch`' version tree, and will not be visible for anyone else working in `/main/LATEST`.

Then with the `subst` from above, you will work within 'mybranch' in `Department\Development`.

```
X:\Department\Development
```

When you want to go public, make the inverse move.

Comment: Thanks for all the info but from your description the key problem of long paths only appears to be "solvable" by using subst.

Comment: NO: a move of the directory within a dev branch is a good workaround